# DropDownList in Gridview Binding error Index 1 is either negative or above rows count

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to bind a drop-down list which is present in `itemtemplate` of my GridView.
But it is giving me the above said error of "Index 1 is either negative or above rows count."

My GridView contains ~100 of rows and I want to bind each drop-down list with specific data. The error is occurring at `onRowDataBoundEvent` and an exception(by the debug tool) is outputting at the `GridBinding` method to bind GridView with the main data.

Here is the code:

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            try
            {
                DropDownList _ddtpcs = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("_ddtsttpc");
                if (_ddtstsubs.SelectedIndex != 0 && _ddtstsubs.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    if (_ddtpcs != null)
                    {
                        _ddtpcs.DataSource = _adl.LoadTopics(long.Parse(_ddtstsubs.SelectedValue));
                           _ddtpcs.DataTextField = "top_nm";
                           _ddtpcs.DataValueField = "top_id";
                           _ddtpcs.DataBind();
                           _ddtpcs.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "message", POPUPBuilder.ShowPopUpMsg(ex.ToString()), true);
            }
        }
```

Here is the code for gridbinding:

```
 _grdqans.DataSource = _adl.LoadQans(long.Parse(_hdntstId.Value));
                _grdqans.DataBind();
```

The drop-down list in GridView is:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddtsttpc" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
```

the LoadTopics method

```
 internal object LoadTopics(long _subId)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_LoadTopics", con.getconnection());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subId", _subId);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            //da.Dispose();
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.closeconnection();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: just to clarify the error occurs after first pass to rowdataboundevent and the gridview of 100 line only shows me a single datarow after exception.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: well i figured out the error the e.row.rowindex is equal to grd.rows.count(which should be count-1) but i dont understand why this is happening.

Comment: plus if you put if (_ddtpcs != null){----code----} part in comments then no error happens and code works fine

Comment: ...which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: the if (_ddtpcs != null){----code----} part is throwing error and just as this error occurs the debugger moves to grid binding event catch(gridbinding method is also in try-catch)

Comment: Oh my goodness, which specific line?!  The actual if statement?  One of the lines inside the if block?  Is it bubbling up from inside the `LoadTopics` method?  It should show you in your debugger where specifically the error occurs.

Comment: no its not from LoadTopics method, the scope of error is within this code, at the first code block 8th line the if clause, as i am reusing the LoadTopics function on other places which is working pretty fine

Comment: alright i rechecked the error is generating after i call the LoadTopic method but the return Datatable contains right data, should i post the LoadTopic method ?

Comment: Yes, please post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update `LoadTopics` method with below code

```
DataTable topicDt = new DataTable();
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_LoadTopics",con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subId", _subId);
    con.Open();
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(topicDt);
    }
}

return topicDt;
```

In your code you are using many class level objects. Those objects can be null or connections etc can be closed. better to have method level objects specially when you working with database. you can reuse connection strings like constants.

Comment: thanks now its working like a charm :), would you please like to explain my mistake, so i can mark it as an answer. thanks @Damith

Comment: @Alok added explanation. One more thing.. you can use `using` blocks for disposable objects. So you don't need to close the connections by code. that block handle it.

Comment: thanks i rechecked your solution with my code, the datatable object was null on calling. thanks again